# JavaScript intersection observer firing before intersection on the first page load

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, intersection-observer

```js
// Options for from bottom observer

const optionsHidden = {
    rootMargin: "0px",
    threshold: 1.0,
}
// From Bottom Scroll Animation using observer ------------------
const observerOne = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {

    entries.forEach((entry) => {
        console.log(entry)
        if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
            entry.target.classList.add('show');
        }
        // else {
        //     entry.target.classList.remove('show');
        // }
    }, optionsHidden);
});

const hiddenElementsOne = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden');
hiddenElementsOne.forEach((el) => observerOne.observe(el));

// // Trial Observer
// const hiddens = document.querySelectorAll(".hidden")

// const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
//     entries => {
//         entries.forEach(entry => {
//             entry.target.classList.toggle("show", entry.isIntersecting)
//             if (entry.isIntersecting) observer.unobserve(entry.target)
//         })
//     },
//     {
//         rootMargin: "-50px",
//     }
// )

// hiddens.forEach(hidden => {
//     observer.observe(hidden)
// })

// New from Right observer

const fromRights = document.querySelectorAll(".fromRight")

const options = {
    rootMargin: "60px",
    threshold: .7,
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
    entries => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            entry.target.classList.toggle("showFromRight", entry.isIntersecting)
            if (entry.isIntersecting) observer.unobserve(entry.target)
        })
    }, options
    // {
    //     threshold: [0.2],
    // }
)

fromRights.forEach(fromRight => {
    observer.observe(fromRight)
});

// New from Right observer for Home Personal image

const fromRightPersonalImg = document.querySelectorAll(".fromRightPersonal")

const optionsPersonal = {
    rootMargin: "0px 5000px 0px 00px",
    threshold: 0.5,
};

const observerPersonal = new IntersectionObserver(
    entries => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            entry.target.classList.toggle("showFromRight", entry.isIntersecting)
            if (entry.isIntersecting) observerPersonal.unobserve(entry.target)
        })
    }, optionsPersonal
    // {
    //     threshold: [0.2],
    // }
)

fromRightPersonalImg.forEach(fromRightPersonal => {
    observerPersonal.observe(fromRightPersonal)
});

// New from Left observer for Experience Pages-----------------------------

const fromLefts = document.querySelectorAll(".fromLeft")

const optionsTwo = {
    rootMargin: "60px",
    threshold: .7,
};

const observerThree = new IntersectionObserver(
    entries => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            entry.target.classList.toggle("showFromLeft", entry.isIntersecting)
            if (entry.isIntersecting) observerThree.unobserve(entry.target)
        })
    }, optionsTwo
    // {
    //     threshold: [0.2],
    // }
)

fromLefts.forEach(fromLeft => {
    observerThree.observe(fromLeft)
});

// New from Left observer for services on homepage -----------------------------

const fromLeftHome = document.querySelectorAll(".fromLeftService")

const serviceOptions = {
    rootMargin: "-50px",
    threshold: 0,
};

const serviceObserver = new IntersectionObserver(
    entries => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
            entry.target.classList.toggle("showFromLeftService", entry.isIntersecting)
            if (entry.isIntersecting) serviceObserver.unobserve(entry.target)
        })
    }, serviceOptions
    // {
    //     threshold: [0.2],
    // }
)

fromLeftHome.forEach(fromLeftService => {
    serviceObserver.observe(fromLeftService)
});
```

```css
/* From BOTTOM SCROLL --------------------- */
/* sets opacity to 0% and transition speed */
.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: blur(5px);
    transform: translateY(100%);
    transition: 2s;
    /* transition: all 2s; Old Style that targets ALL*/
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

/* sets opacity to 100% */
.show {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0);
    transform: translateY(0%);
}

/* From Right Personal Scroll */

/* Personal image on home page */
.fromRightPersonal {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: blur(5px);
    transform: translateX(10%);
    transition: 2s;
    /* transition: all 2s; Old Style that targets ALL*/
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

/* sets opacity to 100% */
.showFromRight {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0);
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

/* From LEFT SCROLL for services on homepage --------------------- */

/* sets opacity to 0% and transition speed */
.fromLeftService {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: blur(5px);
    transform: translateX(-30%);
    transition: 2s;
    /* transition: all 2s; Old Style that targets ALL*/
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

/* sets opacity to 100% */
.showFromLeftService {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: blur(0);
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

/* Delay element's animation  */
.delayOne:nth-child(1) {
    transition-delay: 400ms;
}

.delayTwo:nth-child(2) {
    transition-delay: 800ms;
}

.delayThree:nth-child(3) {
    transition-delay: 1200ms;
}

.delayFour:nth-child(4) {
    transition-delay: 1600ms;
}

.delayFive:nth-child(5) {
    transition-delay: 2000ms;
}

.delaySix:nth-child(6) {
    transition-delay: 2400ms;
}

.delaySeven:nth-child(7) {
    transition-delay: 2800ms;
}

/* From LEFT SCROLL for experience pages --------------------- */

@media (min-width: 800px) {

    /* sets opacity to 0% and transition speed */
    .fromLeft {
        opacity: 0;
        filter: blur(5px);
        transform: translateX(-10%);
        transition: 2s;
        /* transition: all 2s; Old Style that targets ALL*/
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }

    /* sets opacity to 100% */
    .showFromLeft {
        opacity: 1;
        filter: blur(0);
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}

/* Set fromLeft to from bottom on mobile */
@media (max-width: 800px) {

    /* sets opacity to 0% and transition speed */
    .fromLeft {
        opacity: 0;
        filter: blur(5px);
        transform: translateY(100%);
        transition: 2s;
        /* transition: all 2s; Old Style that targets ALL*/
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }

    /* sets opacity to 100% */
    .showFromLeft {
        opacity: 1;
        filter: blur(0);
        transform: translateY(0%);
    }
}

/* From RIGHT SCROLL --------------------- */
@media (min-width: 800px) {

    /* sets opacity to 0% and transition speed */
    .fromRight {
        opacity: 0;
        filter: blur(5px);
        transform: translateX(15%);
        transition: 2s;
        /* transition: all 2s; Old Style that targets ALL*/
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
    }

    /* sets opacity to 100% */
    .showFromRight {
        opacity: 1;
        filter: blur(0);
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}

/* Set from right scroll to from bottom for mobile --------------------- */
@media (max-width: 800px) {

    /* sets opacity to 0% and transition speed */
    .fromRight {
        opacity: 0;
        filter: blur(5px);
        transform: translateY(100%);
        transition: 2s;
        /* transition: all 2s; Old Style that targets ALL*/
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
    }

    /* sets opacity to 100% */
    .showFromRight {
        opacity: 1;
        filter: blur(0);
        transform: translateY(0%);
    }
}
```

```html
<main>
        <!-- START OF TRIAL -->

        <!-- Instructional Design Services-->
        <section>
            <!-- Main Text -->
            <h1 class="h1_font_size service_page_h1s hidden">Instructional Design Services</h1>
            <!-- Responive grid that contains instructional design icons -->
            <div class="img_grid_secondary">

                <!-- Instructional Design Methodologies-->
                <div class="img_grid_div_secondary fromLeft delayOne">
                    <img src="images/instructional_design_methodologies.png" class="interactive_noclick"
                        style="width: 70%;" alt="Instructional design methodologies and services icon"
                        onclick="window.location.href='#'">
                    <div class="flex_wrap text_sizing_secondary" style="max-width: 70%;">
                        <h2 class="h2_font_size h2_spacing">Instructional Design Methodologies</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Course Development Tools -->
                <div class="img_grid_div_secondary fromLeft delayTwo">
                    <img src="images/instructional_design_development_services_near_me.png" class="interactive_noclick"
                        style="width: 70%;" alt="course development and instructional development services near me icon"
                        onclick="window.location.href='#'">
                    <div class="flex_wrap" style="max-width: 60%;">
                        <h2 class="h2_font_size h2_spacing">Course Development Tools</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Adult Learning Theories -->
                <div class="img_grid_div_secondary fromLeft delayThree">
                    <img src="images/adult_learning_theories.png" class="interactive_noclick" style="width: 70%;"
                        alt="adult learning theories and services near me" onclick="window.location.href='#'">
                    <div class="flex_wrap" style="max-width: 50%;">
                        <h2 class="h2_font_size h2_spacing">Adult Learning Theories</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Separator -->
        <hr class="dividers hidden">
        <!-- Agile for Instructional Design -->
        <section>
            <div class="hidden">
                <h2 class="h2_font_size h2_spacing">Agile for Instructional Design</h2>
            </div>
            <!-- Instructional Design Process Steps -->
            <div class="process_grid">
                <!-- Planning -->
                <div class="hidden">
                    <img src="images/instructional_design_planning_process.png"
                        class="process_steps interactive_noclick" alt="Agile for instructional design planning phase">
                </div>
                <!-- Design -->
                <div class="hidden">
                    <img src="images/instructional_design_design_process.png" class="process_steps interactive_noclick"
                        alt="Agile for instructional design, design phase">
                </div>
                <!-- Development -->
                <div class="hidden">
                    <img src="images/instructional_design_development_process.png"
                        class="process_steps interactive_noclick" alt="Agile for instructional design deployment phase">
                </div>
                <!-- Testing and Review -->
                <div class="hidden">
                    <img src="images/instructional_design_testing_process.png" class="process_steps interactive_noclick"
                        alt="Agile for instructional design testing and review phase">
                </div>
                <!-- Deployment -->
                <div class="hidden" style="padding-bottom: 12px;">
                    <img src="images/instructional_design_deployment_process.png"
                        class="process_steps interactive_noclick" alt="Agile for instructional design deployment phase">
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

I am hosting my site [https://thomaskalman.com/](https://thomaskalman.com). I am using the JavaScript Intersection Observer API to make my elements animate on scroll. I have the Root Margin and Thresholds set. However, on the first page load of the "Instructional Design," "Web & UX Design," and "Multimedia Design" pages the observers further down the page activate too early. This problem happens only sometimes, and the issue can be resolved by refreshing the page: when it does happen. Too further elaborate, every element should animate onto the page when in the viewport. I've been working on this issue for a few weeks now and have not been able to resolve the issue. Thanks!

Intersection observer API JavaScript

[How it should look before scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MxWM.png)

[Example of it loading elements before scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrGZK.png)